# WPF doesn't prevent duplicate tabindex input

Tags: c#, wpf

When I set the control's tabindex to a repeated value, the error doesn't occur.

Focus on the two controls with a tabindex value of 2, first focus on Textbox 5, and then focus on Textbox 6. How does it work?

Why not prevent users from entering duplicate values?

```html
<TextBox x:Name="Textbox0" TabIndex="0"  Height="23" Margin="5,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Width="505"/>
       <TextBox x:Name="Textbox1" TabIndex="4"  Height="23" Margin="5,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox"  Width="505"/>
       <TextBox x:Name="Textbox2" TabIndex="1"  Height="23" Margin="5,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox"  Width="505"/>
       <Button x:Name="Textbox3" TabIndex="3" Content="Button" Height="40" Margin="5" Width="505"/>
       <Button x:Name="Textbox5" TabIndex="2" Content="Button" Height="40" Margin="5"  Width="505"/>
       <Button x:Name="Textbox6" TabIndex="2" Content="Button"  Height="40" Margin="5" Width="505"/>
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

> A tab index can consist of any valid integer greater than or equal to zero, lower numbers being earlier in the tab order. **If more than one control on the same parent control has the same tab index, the z-order of the controls determines the order to cycle through the controls.**